# Odd CPU Throttling Issue

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, temperature, throttling

Just got a Thinkpad P15s (Laptop), and I'm experiencing a very odd issuing with the CPU throttling under heavy load and low temperatures. This can last anywhere from 1 minute-10 minute, where afterwards the CPU will skyrocket to an overclocked speed, and the application will no longer be lagging heavily. Then, this will last for some time, and then the cycle repeats.

So as you can see in the picture, my CPU is throttling down to an abysmal 0.39ghz (basically making every program near unusable). I have core temp open in the picture, and as you can see, the CPU is only at a meager 40 degrees celsius, which is nothing at all for computer hardware.

I am connected to a power source, and all my power management are on performance, meaning it should not be due to the laptop attempting to conserve power.

This laptop has a discrete GPU but I have noticed when I am using a GPU-heavy application, that it uses the Intel Integrated Graphics card.

These issues seem unrelated but I believe they may some how be conected. Perhaps the iGPU is causing some sort of throttling with the CPU?

Or maybe the CPU is experiencing high temps while in an overclock speed, and then clocks down to 0.39ghz to cool off.

If this is the case, is there a way to prevent the overclock speeds and simply run at a moderate 2.4ghz to balance speed and temperature? I certainly don't need the full overclock 3.9ghz. Might play around with the power management and see what happens.

In this screenshot that the CPU is under load and is running a CPU-intensive program. So it is not throttling because it is idle.

Update: Did some experimenting. There is an extremely low threshold for thermal throttling. Upon closing all applications, and reaching a temperature under 40C, the throttling suddenly stopped and clock speeds returned to normal. This can't be right, right? 40C seems like an awfully low temperature to thermal throttle at. Someone please help

[image: Weird throttling]

Comment: Use Lenovo System Update to update all drivers including BIOS and Power Driver. Reset Power Management to Default, restart and see if the issue is ongoing.

Comment: @John Completely updated. Just checked the Lenovo Commercial Vantage.

Comment: Just got a Thinkpad P15s   ....  Contact Lenovo Support because if all is set to default. there may be a hardware issue.

Comment: Update: Did some experimenting. There is an extremely low threshold for thermal throttling. Upon closing all applications, and reaching a temperature under 40C, the throttling suddenly stopped and clock speeds returned to normal. This can't be right, right? 40C seems like an awfully low temperature to thermal throttle at. Someone please help. @John

Comment: Guess: There are different levels of throttling depending on the temperature, the first level starts at 40C. For some reason, what is supposed to be mild throttling at this temperature hits really hard on your system. Might be hardware, do do contact support.

Comment: Is there a cpu throttling option in the bios?

Comment: I do have a similar problem with my ThinkPad P14sGen2(Intel) when using USB-PD(60W) as its power supply. The genuine AC/DC power supply for the PC is 65W.
I suspect some CPU throttling due to a power shortage occurs. Check your power supply is sufficient for your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You CPU is the
[Intel® Core i5-1135G7 Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208658/intel-core-i5-1135g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html),
with a specified temperature limit (T JUNCTION) of 100°C.
Your image of Core Temp shows the same limit.

You shouldn't then have any throttling at 40°C, unless you have changed the
CPU clock or voltage (if you did, better undo it).

If the thermal throttling parameters have somehow been corrupted,
you could try the following two utilities to undo:

- [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/)
- [Intel Extreme Tuning Utility (Intel XTU)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29183/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-)

You would find more information for running ThrottleStop in the article
[The ThrottleStop Guide (2021): How to Lower Temperatures, Increase Performance and Boost Battery Life](https://www.ultrabookreview.com/31385-the-throttlestop-guide/).

If the computer is new, you could also get in touch with Lenovo Support.