# Is there a fix for my laptop running at 0.39GHz for absolutely no reason?

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, throttling

I have an ideapad laptop, and for whatever reason it's suddenly started to randomly drop to 0.39 GHz for absolutely no reason. Ive tried setting minimum and maximum CPU state to 100% but that didn't help so I assumed it was throttling. I've gone through multiple different threads of the same problem but none of the solutions either apply to me or work. It's been about a week and I've tried basically everything to try and fix it.

Usually my CPU runs at around 3.36 constantly which is the turbo clock for it, and around 2.10 when on a low load. It never used to drop before 1 and now when it does the entire system slows down. If anyone has a solution that would be great.

Comment: IIRC this is a well-known problem (CPU throttling being stuck). Searching the net should yield plenty of information. Dunno if solutions exist though.

Comment: See [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/1679451/ryzen-4600h-cpu-stuck-at-0-39-ghz) and [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/1664542/odd-cpu-throttling-issue) and [link3](https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes).

Answer (score 0):

Does that issue occur with other OS? You might test one, such as [Live Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/), run from USB (no installation needed).

If that *does* run at full speed, then you have a *work-around* for intensive tasks:

- Either temporarily run from USB -- many applications are included on the USB, such as *Firefox* browser, and *LibreOffice* suite, equivalent to MS *Office*, and able to handle *Office*-formatted files.
- Or *permanently* install Linux, either dual boot or by itself. Many Windows apps, though not all, run well under *wine* in Linux. You'd need to test to see if Linux meets your needs.

Note that running Linux **under Windows OS** as a *virtual machine* likely would be *even slower* than Windows, though.